# How can I configure Apache and LDAP to allow a second authentication attempt?

Tags: apache, ldap

I just got Apache/LDAP authentication working (almost) on a new SLES 10 server.

When I visit one of the protected areas on my website I get the Apache Authentication pop-up window where I can LDAP authenticate to gain access to the protected folder.

But I'm getting wierd behaviour.

If I type in a valid user but the incorrect password, it lets me retry authentication.

If I type in a non-valid user (like 'aldfklsf' or even leave the username field blank) then I get an error 500 page and do not get the opportunity to retry authentication.

I have cache disabled...  Try to refresh the page to get the Apache authentication window to come back and it doesn't.  I just keep getting the error 500 page.  Looking in the Apache error logs it says: user aldfklsf not found, every time I refresh the page.  It's like it's hanging on to that username.

**Is there some setting in Apache that will allow me to attempt to authenticate again?**

Here's the entirety of the conf file that is protecting the directory:

```
<Directory "/media/nss/VOL1/ProtectedDir">
  Options Indexes Multiviews
  AllowOverride None
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Protected"
  Require valid-user
  AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
  AuthzLDAPAuthoritative Off
  AuthBasicProvider ldap 
  AuthLDAPURL ldap://10.20.32.3/o=wlwv?uid?sub
</Directory>
```

**An update.**  I found this in the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/misc/FAQ.html#authauthoritative):

> Under normal circumstances, the Apache
>   access control modules will pass
>   unrecognized user IDs on to the next
>   access control module in line. Only if
>   the user ID is recognized and the
>   password is validated (or not) will it
>   give the usual success or
>   "authentication failed" messages.

This seems to be the answer.  Unfortunately I do not understand Apache enough to take the information from that page and implement it so that it works correctly.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, got it figured out.  Here is the **simple solution** in case anyone else has this issue.

Changing:

AuthBasicAuthoritative Off

to

AuthBasicAuthoritative On

was all it took.